# Estimation from noisy observation

Tags: linear-algebra, estimation, noise, parameter-estimation

Assume that you have access to a noisy observation (static vector) y, which can be expressed as $y=x+b$ where the static vector $x$ is unknown. The noise $b$ is an independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) zero-mean noise distributed according to a Gaussian distribution with covariance $C$. The mean of the noise b (0) and its covariance $C$ are known, as well as the noisy measurement $y$. What is the best technique to estimate $x$ from $y$ please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the noise term is iid Gaussian with zero mean and equal variances, the most likely value for each $x_i$ is just $y_i$. If you have some reason to believe the $x_i$ have some prior distribution then you can apply Bayesian inference and then choose the posterior mean vector as a point estimate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Bey. That is what I was supposing but when the covariance of the noise $b$ is high, the value of each $x_i$ can be far from the value of $y_i$. I was wondering if there was a more efficient technique to estimate $x$ from $y$ in such a case.

Comment: @G.Trav in your post you specify b is iid Gaussian, so C is the identity matrix. Are you saying the error for one x may be related to another?

Comment: @G.Trav to clarify — C is diagonal with equal entries (per iid)

Comment: You are right, C is a diagonal matrix with equal entries, thanks.

Comment: Actually, I was just saying that the value of one $b_i$ can be large even if $b$ is a zero-mean noise, which implies that the value of the corresponding $x_i$ can be far from $y_i$. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to estimate $x_i$ from $y_i$.

Comment: @G.Trav the most-likely estimate is as given in my answer in this case — MLEs tend to be efficient as well.